# Android - Hide keyboard on SimpleAdapter

Tags: android

I created a Simple Adapter to costumize my auto complete textview, and I would like to hide the keyboard when the user clicks at the auto complete text.

I already created a function to hide de keyboard but I'm having some issues using it on SimpleAdapter, I only need to get the current activity to call the function.

Hide keyboard  function here:

```
public static void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity activity) {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) activity
                .getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus()
                .getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
```

SimpleAdapter code:

```
public class ACAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {

    Context context;

    public ACAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data,
            int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, data, resource, from, to);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public View getView(final int position, final View convertView,
            final ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        final String id = (String) ((Map) getItem(position))
                .get(EventsFragment.ITEM_SECTIONID);

        v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                GetSpots task = new GetSpots();
                task.execute(id);

                EventsFragment.refresh = false;

                EventsFragment.loading_bg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                hideSoftKeyboard(context.getActivity());

            }

        });

        return v;

    }

}
```

So, i tried to use "context.getActivity" but is not working, I'm receiving this warning:

```
The method getActivity() is undefined for the type Context
```

Is there any way to do what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try cast your context into type **Activity** ?

```
hideSoftKeyboard((Activity)context);
```

Comment: Didn't work: "The method hideSoftKeyboard(Activity) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}"

Comment: @RúbenDias Just a friendly reminder, be careful with `activity.getCurrentFocus()` as this might return you `null`

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I will fix that.